# bash file in mac not functioning properly. How to restart or remove it? It is preventing me from doing anything meaningful in Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

The Terminal of my Mac when I open it says this :

```
Last login: Sun Jul 21 00:07:48 on ttys000
-bash: export: `/Users/vishveshbhat/Desktop/flutter/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/vishveshbhat/Desktop/flutter/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:': not a valid identifier
Ganeshs-MacBook-Air:~ vishveshbhat$
```

And whenever I enter a command, I get "command not found". What to do?

Comment: Could you run `/bin/bash -x` or `/usr/bin/bash -x` (whichever one it is on macOS) and try to find the mention of the specific file that has these paths? (though it's probably ~/.bashrc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of your startup scripts you probably have

```
export PATH= /Users/vishveshbhat/Desktop/flutter/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:$PATH
```

This sets the `PATH` variable to an empty string and causes the first error. The culprit is the space character next to `=`.

Then, in the same or another script that also gets sourced, you probably have

```
export PATH = /Users/vishveshbhat/Desktop/flutter/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:$PATH
```

*or* maybe:

```
export $PATH= /Users/vishveshbhat/Desktop/flutter/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:$PATH
```

or something similar. This causes the second and the third error (note `$PATH` now resolves to nothing). The right general syntax is like

```
export var=value
# or with many variables at once
export var1=value1 var2=value2 var3="value3 with spaces maybe"
```

So in your case:

```
export PATH="/Users/vishveshbhat/Desktop/flutter/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:$PATH"
```

where

- there is no space next to `=`;
- the variable name (just after `export`) is not preceded by `$`.

---

To fix this you need to temporarily fix your `PATH`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Then in this particular console you should be able to call `vi`, `nano` or whatever editor you use and fix the script(s). Files to check:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
/etc/profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

(some of them may not exist, this is normal). If any of them sources another script, check it as well.

It's possible that two separate lines are invalid and each tries to add `/Users/vishveshbhat/Desktop/flutter/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` to the beginning of your `$PATH`. If you fix this, the string will be added twice, which will probably cause no harm, but it's excessive and inelegant. Check carefully. Keep in mind some startup scripts are loaded in some circumstances, others in other.

Comment: That really helped. Thanks a lot!!